# validate end date equal to greater than start date

Tags: date, jquery-validate

I want to check whether end date is greater than or equal to start date, with jquery validate. It is validating end date greater than start date, but it is not permitting end date equal to start date,

here is my code -

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", 
function(value, element, params) {
    if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
        return new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val());
    }
    return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val()) 
        || (Number(value) > Number($(params).val())); 
},'Must be greater than {0}.');

jQuery("#collect_and_delivery").validate({ 
        errorElement:'div',               
        rules: {                    
                from:{
                        required:true
                     },
                to:{
                    required:true
                },
                start_date:{
                    required:true
                },
                 end_date:{
                    required:true,
                    greaterThan: "#start_date"              
                }
        },
        messages: {
               from:"Please enter collect address",
               to:"Please enter delivery address",
               start_date:"Please enter shipping collect date",
               end_date:
               { 
                    required:"Please enter shipping delivery date",
                    greaterThan:"Delivery date and Collect date should be proper"
               }
        }                
    });
```

Comment: Bro, use `is greater than or equal to (>=)` in your custom validator method `greaterThan`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `is greater than or equal to`(**`>=`**) in your custom method `greaterThan`.

Change this line:

```
return new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val());
```

To:

```
return new Date(value) >= new Date($(params).val());
```

Enjoy...

Comment: Bro, it works for me check the [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kishor_subedi/KLQyw/)

Comment: yes, it is working, my code was so messy, i made change in another file. sorry.Thank you.

Comment: Bro its not working properly .. Its checking only day .. not the year and month

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use simple javascript to compare ethe date. Here is one; simple and easier.

```
 function compareDate() {
    var str = document.getElementById("start_date").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end_date").value;
    var year = str.substring(0,4);
    var month = str.substring(5,7);
    var date = str.substring(8,10);
    var endYear = end.substring(0,4);
    var endMonth = end.substring(5,7);
    var endDate = end.substring(8,10);
    var startDate = new Date(year, month-1, date);
    var endDate = new Date(endYear, endMonth-1, endDate);

    if (startDate > endDate) {
      alert('start date should be less than end date');
       return false;
    } 
    else { return true; }
}
```