# jQuery validation to compare start and end date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two fields. One for person_start_date and another for person_end_date. Both has three separate fields for year, month, date. I would like to validate  like Person end date >  Person start date. Thanks in advance.

html.erb

```
<%= datetime_select :person_start_date %>


   <select id="person_start_date_1i" name="person[start_date(1i)]"> ... </select>
   <select id="person_start_date_2i" name="person[start_date(2i)]"> ... </select>
   <select id="person_start_date_3i" name="person[start_date(3i)]"> ... </select>
```

html.erb

```
<%= datetime_select :person_end_date %>


  <select id="person_end_date_1i" name="person[end_date(1i)]"> ... </select>
  <select id="person_end_date_2i" name="person[end_date(2i)]"> ... </select>
  <select id="person_end_date_3i" name="person[end_date(3i)]"> ... </select>
```

Comment: Show us what you tried?

Comment: What sort of values (e.g. 01, 1, Jan, January)? Which select is which (e.g. is person_start_date_1i the day, month or year)?

Comment: see the above, below the erb code there is a html

Comment: Here I can add only jQuery validator add method to validate. I can add any alert. So what I am searching for names to validate the fro and to fields with all the hints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a suggestion :

```
var startDate = new Date(
    $('#person_start_date_1i').val(),
    $('#person_start_date_2i').val() - 1,
    $('#person_start_date_3i').val()
);
var endDate = new Date(
    $('#person_end_date_1i').val(),
    $('#person_end_date_2i').val() - 1,
    $('#person_end_date_3i').val()
);
if (endDate > startDate) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have year, month and day values as numbers (they can be Type number or string), you can create a Date like:

```
var dStart = new Date(year, --month, day);
```

Note that for calendar month 1 the javascript month number is 0 (zero) as months are zero indexed, hence `--month`.

and you can compare two dates directly:

```
if (dEnd < dStart) {
  // end is before start
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think either of these links should answer your question in general:

[validate end date equal to greater than start date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917172/validate-end-date-equal-to-greater-than-start-date)

[Validate that end date is greater than start date with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833997/end-date-greater-than-start-date-jquery-validation)

UPDATE:

This link describes exactly your question and gives a good solution for it

[jQuery validate date field for seperate year, month, date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040267/jquery-validate-date-field-for-seperate-year-month-date)

Comment: You can retrieve values of months, date, and year from input  fields (select dropdowns) and construct a Date object in JQuery, then use the above links to validate them.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/GGsMx/

cant get simpler than this..

```
var date1 = Date.parse("2012-11-18");
var date2 = Date.parse("2011-11-18");
if (date1 > date2) {
    alert ("Error!");
}
else{
    alert("correct")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The important aspect is that such comparison fails because of date format used.
Mostly it works with mm-dd-yyyy format because PC have same regional settings and it looks like correct format, however thats not the case. 
For compatibility various languages/platforms keep dates in year-month-date format. 
Hence,  it is best to explicitly convert date to yyyy-mm-dd format and do the conversion, specially when you are using dd-mm-yyy (Aus or European format).